# How do you make the perfect S curve?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I have tried using the Curve Modifier but it doesn't form a perfect S curve. The Bezier curve is perfectly curved but objects with Curve Modifier are not perfectly curved.
[image: Curve Modifier]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mesh and the curve need to start in the same place for best results.
Your mesh is probably a bit offset.

1. Set both origins to the same place
2. Make sure both curve and mesh *start* at their origin point
3. Done.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you very much sir. 

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your project.